# Laravel returns CSRF Token mismatch (responsecode 419) after Ajax login

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Problem: When I login the user via an Ajax call, Laravel returns an 419 CSRF token mismatch on the next Ajax Post on the same page.

On a checkout page, I have a login button for existing users. When clicked it presents the user a login modal. If the credentials match, the user is logged in without a page refresh. When the user does not have an account, a signup modal is presented that registers the user and signs them in.

When the user finishes the checkout process and submit the form, Laravel returns a CSRF token mismatch error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that after a successful login, Laravel sends a login response using the AuthenticatesUsers trait.

The login response then calls the regenerate method on the session(), which generates a new CSRF token. So the csrf token you used to login the user, is no longer valid for the next POST requests.

```
/**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 204)
                    : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

I handled this by returning the new csrf token in the successful login response, and store this for use in the next POST requests. By store I mean save it in the JavaScript as a variable, or in my case using React.js set in the application's state.

In the Auth/LoginController I added the authenticated method, which overrides the same method from the AuthenticatesUsers trait.

Then after the line where the request is validated, I check if this is an Ajax request and return the new CSRF token.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {

        $credentials = array (
            'email'    => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->get('password'),
        );

        $valid = Auth::validate($credentials);
        
        if ($valid && $request->ajax()) {

            return response()->json([
                'auth'     => auth()->check(),
                'user'     => $user,
                'intended' => $this->redirectPath(),
                'csrf'     => csrf_token(),
            ]);
        }

        // Nothing changed from here on
    }
```